# Can you get a job if you know XHTML, CSS and Basic PHP?

Tags: php, css, xhtml

If you know XHTML, CSS and Basic PHP, can you get a job with those skills and what type of jobs should i be looking for? Thanks

Comment: People have gotten jobs with less...

Comment: junior web integrator: you'll be given word documents to convert into semantic html. At best. i suggest you turn the question the other way around, something like: what do i really want to do with my life? And then do whatever it takes to get to that point.

Comment: yea, I really don't know what I want to do with my life so I thought if I can get a job with those skills.

Comment: Belongs on http://careeroverflow.com

Comment: I know a guy on just under 50k gbp who knows allot less; gift of the gab can take you further than actual skill (unfortunately) the world is full of ass bags like that though. Better to get your head around Javascript &&|| jquery and a proper grasp of creating semantic, accessible websites.

Comment: Highly depending on location and many social factors. On my city, for example, development related jobs are horribly underpaid and heavily coveted (too much offer for not so much demand, I guess).

Comment: careeroverflow.com? Is there an overflow site for *everything*?

Comment: @Tim: Stackexchange, actually. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites

Comment: Thanks! I should learn how to write correct English first i guess.

Answer (score 7):

These kinds of questions tend to depend on your local economy, your personal and technical skills, and lots of other things that no one here has the foggiest notion of.

I'd recommend looking at Monster.com, Dice.com, or some other job board that will take in geographic specifics, skills, etc. and give you jobs that match.  It's not a good question to ask here, because we really can't answer it for your case.

Answer (score 2):

Sound like a good candidate for a UI developer.

Some Javascript would definitely help.

Answer (score 2):

Junior Web Developer would be what you would go for. When I got my first job (as Junior Web Developer) I knew XHTML and CSS, with a small bit of jQuery. It may also be called "Front-end web developer", the "Front-end" referring to HTML/CSS/JS skills (client-side languages).

Comment: Yes i do agree with you Russell, front end developer.

Answer (score 1):

Web Design would be the most appropriate field for you.

Most people who identify themselves as "web designers" have these skills.

Other people, who have strong ground in PHP or JavaScript, identify with "X Web developer" - where "X" would be "front-end" (JavaScript), "back-end" (any server-side language(s)) or "end-to-end" (both)

Comment: Yes.  This is how I self identify - though it is often hard to make this distinction clear to others.  "No, I'm not an artist..."

Comment: In my opinion, Web Design is a bit differently classified. I'd expect more a photoshop guy than a CSS guy. Basic XHTML+CSS+PHP is imo just (Junior) Web Developer.

Answer (score 1):

Thats how most people start i would think.  You'd pretty much an html peon.  The equivalent of a fry cook with slightly better pay.  You have to be pretty into it to make it past the initial stages. But these are highly tranfereable skills so if you choose this as your path, then there is no way you can't benefit from a job like this.

Myself, i started out with pretty much the same skill set you have now as a web developer( looking back on it, i wouldn't call what i did actual 'development').  I was able to find an employer that was ok with me learning on the job(which i believe is the only real way to learn).  I stated out making cookie cutter php/html templates.  Through the next couple years i honed my css/html/skills.  I got quicker, my markup got smaller, and i didn't dig myself into cross-browser css nightmares anymore.  Gradually I was exposed to many things that i had no concept of a few years prior. Now i build custom web apps using in django and python, oscommerce builds, and some server administration as needed.  From here there still so many different disciplines to grow into that it continually dives me to learn more and get better.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the language doesn't mean you can design worth beans. It's your portfolio that gets you jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. If not with a company, at least by freelancing and people can get lots doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why people here are so pessimistic with the skills that you mentioned....(junior web developer?...etc)

The way I see it, the web's coming back to the browser (with HTML5, all that AJAX stuff), so the skills you mentioned would certainly be something that would be a valuable asset to a company within these next few years (and I'm not talking Junior developer level)

It just depends how far deep you want to go down with the technologies that you mentioned.

I would advise you to go as far down with it as possible...the sky's the limit then!